# When is it proper to abbreviate first to 1st?

Tags: abbreviations, numbers

When is it proper to use `1st` instead of `first`?

For example, is the correct sentence acceptable?

> Can you give more detail about why you 1st got involved?

I tried finding some authoritative source on that but failed.

Comment: Well, for starters that right there is not an ordinal. It's an adverb. So of course you can't abbreviate it like that. It makes about as much sense as writing "I saw her just a 2nd ago".

Comment: The abbreviated form is very unusual for 'first' as the adverb intercategorial polyseme (She arrived first, detail about why you first got involved) though doubtless acceptable in textspeak. It's unusual for 'first' as an adjective / attributive noun / quantifier // pronoun in even slightly formal writing (the first violins, the first man in space // first among equals, the first starts tomorrow). It's mainly restricted to lists.

Comment: I changed the title of the question to remove the notion of ordinal

Comment: Dates and competition results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Barring cases of extreme abbreviations (where one might use such abbreviations as "t ppl complaind abt t difficulty n reading &c", such as some live internet chat room, or mediaeval manuscripts) then *1st* must only be used when *first* is an actual ordinal; that is it could be replaced by "in position number one" and make the same sense, albeit clumsily:

> She was the 1st guest to arrive.
>
> *She 1st greeted her host, then took off her coat.

The first is technically okay, because the *first* here is indeed an ordinal, positioning her within a series, the second is not because it is an adverb only.

While technically okay, we would generally still not use the abbreviation in the first case, because it's not a context where we would use any abbreviations. Rather, the abbreviations are best restricted to cases where we are going to talk of several ordinals, (i.e. where we would also talk of the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc.) or where an ordinal is strongly expected (e.g. in dates). If in doubt, lean toward not using it.

Comment: I think that assertions with such authority ('must only be used' / 'the second is not [OK]') need references when given in an answer. Which lack is why I posted as a 'comment'.

Comment: 'then 1st must only be used when first is an actual ordinal' --> so necessary but not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

You must just be clear and consistent with the method you use. In seventh grade my teacher told me that anything like "1st" that is under 10 should be written out like "first" but anything over ten can be abbreviated such as "1st". Of course, that was in the fifties, so things might have changed since then :) Good luck! ;)